# How to efficiently render content based on user permission? (Using permission based access control)

Tags: html, postgresql, vue.js, access-control

Rendering based on roles is a common thing, you have the admin, moderator and user and render it accordingly. However, how can I render it based on general rules? This structure below may help:

```
---Platform (platform)

-----Manage User (permissionGroup)

---------Delete (permission)

---------Update

---------Create

---------Update
```

I could render every permission inside the platform like this, but the UX/UI wouldn't be good, so the wanted approach would be something like:

```
---Platform (platform)

-----Manage User(permissionGroup)
```

Then inside the manage user I could list (permission) them, and for each, buttons called Update and Delete would appear.

Simplified tables below:

```sql
platform(
    id
    icon (for automatic rendering purposes)
    name (for automatic rendering purposes)
);

permissionGroup(
    id,
    icon (for automatic rendering purposes)
    name (for automatic rendering purposes)
    route
    platformID
);

permission(
    id
    permissionGroupID
    name
    isActive
);

userPermission(
    id
    permissionID
    userID
);
```

What is the best way I could render the content based on these permission rules?

Answer (score 1):

After some googling I found this [lib](https://github.com/stalniy/casl), which looks promising. In nutshell, it basically lets you define all the permissions for current role in single file without code duplication. It also has a vue integration.

Comment: I found it incredible confusing on how to approach it correctly. How could I adapt it to my model?

Answer (score 0):

you can try CASL. check below . 
 https://github.com/stalniy/casl/blob/master/packages/casl-react/README.md